# How can I check if a variable exists in Scheme?

Tags: lisp, scheme

Is there a way to check if a variable exists in Scheme?  Even doing things like (if variable) or (null? variable) cause errors because the variable is not defined.  Is there some function that returns whether or not a variable exists?

Comment: Why would you ever need this?

Comment: @Paul: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: That's why I posted it as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: I am not a scheme expert (or novice. :o) - but can you trap the error as a condition and returned based on that condition?

Comment: @Paul Nathan: not in standard R5RS -- I'm not sure about R6RS, but I'm confident that it will be possible in R7RS since they're standardizing some exception handling mechanism (but then, they are likely  also to standardise environment enquiries).

Comment: Well, it's not possible in R7RS-small, as I expected.  The "environment inquiries" of R7RS-large have to do with the outer environment, things like the machine's name and the name of the OS, not the Scheme variable environment.

Comment: @paul I don't know if there are truly good reasons in Scheme, but I have an example in C which should conceptually translate: on [this line of my `errnoname.c` file](https://github.com/mentalisttraceur/errnoname/blob/c8b427a871305e37f826a07231d7b0730fa3b5bf/errnoname.c#L81) I have to either have a line of code, or not, based entirely on the unstandardized variations in an external library: if the library on that system defines an `EBADMACHO` error, I need a line of code to handle it, otherwise, that line of code would be erroneous because `EBADMACHO` would not be defined.

Comment: @paul So we can imagine a similar use-case in Scheme: someone wants to write a library, but this library needs to smooth over variations in different implementations that it wants to support. Ideally, in a lot of such cases, the "proper" solution would not require such hacks, but sometimes the "proper" solution requires cooperation from the underlying implementations, and the whole problem is that their releases up to this point have not done their part for that proper solution. (For example, ideally `errnoname` would be provided by the standard library, which knows what is or isn't defined.)

Answer (score 8):

This feature is built into Mit-Scheme.

```
#lang scheme   
(define x "hello world")
(environment-bound? (nearest-repl/environment) 'x)
(environment-bound? (nearest-repl/environment) 'not-x)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example in Racket:

```
#lang racket
(define x 1)
(define-namespace-anchor ns)
(define (is-bound? nm)
  (define r (gensym))
  (not (eq? r (namespace-variable-value nm #t
                                            (lambda () r) 
                                            (namespace-anchor->namespace ns)))))

(is-bound? 'x)
(is-bound? 'not-bound-here)
```

Answer (score 4):

You want to ask questions to the environment. This is not possible with R5RS, and I'm not sure about R6RS. I certainly would like to do that using just the Scheme standard (and this *may* be part of R7RS -- look for  "Environment enquiries" in the [list of items they are likely going to work on](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0Ar8UUpsyGZ0wdEtoMy0ta1piRDcwZUVQZ29wbk8yNEE&hl=en&output=html)).

As far as I can tell there are currently only *ad-hoc* solutions to that so you'll have to read your implementation's documentation.

Chicken supports that with the `oblist` egg (it lets you obtain a list of all interned symbols), and also with the `environments` egg, which lets you specificaly ask if one symbol is bound.

Depending on your implementation if may be possible to test this by making a reference to the variable and catching an exception, then checking if it was a not-bound exception, or something similar to that.

Answer (score 3):

According to R6RS, it's a syntax violation to make a call to an unbound variable.

http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-12.html#node_sec_9.1

However, depending on your implementation there should be a way (theoretically, at least) to query the environment and check if a variable is a member. You'd need to do some further reading for that, however.

http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-17.html#node_idx_1268

Comment: However, R6RS compiler implementations are allowed to refuse to compile programs that have syntax violations.  I doubt this will be part of R7RS either.